# bug in mysql count function: zero results with two conditions

Tags: count, mysql-5.6

I'm working with a LAMP server (it's a bananapi) with MYSQL 5.6 server installed on it. I have a table with several fields.

From mysql command line, if I run:

```
select * from tbl_name where field1=val1 and field2=val2
```

it returns N results.

If I run instead:

```
select COUNT(*) from tbl_name where field1=val1 and field2=val2
```

it returns 0..

In particular, field1 and field2 are foreign key values to other two separate tables. All tables are InnoDB.

It's a bug???

Comment: Not that it should matter but what is N? Throw `min(field1), max(field1), min(field2), max(field2)` in there to see if you get real values or just nulls.

Comment: Consider NULL values?

Comment: I tried to be generic, N is a number greater than 0. In particular, for example, if I run:
`SELECT * FROM tbl_prodotti WHERE categoria_id=228 and marca_id=23`
it returns 18 rows. With count(*) and same values, it return 0 instead!

Comment: @Giuseppe I understood what you were doing. Did you try my other suggestion? I agree that it should be 18 rather  than 0.

Comment: Also try `select field1, field2, count(*) from ...` since MySQL lets you mix aggregates with column data.

Comment: `min(field1), max(field1), min(field2), max(field2)` : no null values! If I try: `select field1, field2, count(*) from ...` it returns this tuple: NULL,NULL,0

Comment: What about `count(field1), count(field2)`?

Comment: It returns 0,0 :-(

Comment: I don't know enough about MySQL to suggest any weird settings that would impact this. It certainly sounds very odd. I wish you had enough rep to post a screenshot. Is there any possibility you're querying different databases?

Comment: I tried with sakila database (mysql test database). An analog operation works well, as expected! Just for info: the tables in sakila db are smaller than mine...

Answer (score 0):

are you enabled fulltextsearch on the table?

i have same problem and fixed by this trik!

select count(*) from (select * from tbl_name where field1=val1 and field2=val2) as t

Comment: Yes, I have enabled fulltext search on field3 and field4 of the same table. I'm going to try your solution just now! :-)

Comment: Absurd: today I tried again my simple query and it works!.. O_o'' perhaps a mysql automatic update on ubuntu?

Comment: yes! randomly works simple query! but, my query always works!!! it maybe bug in mysql